# What is this haskell syntax?

Tags: haskell, syntax, record

I just ran across the following syntax in a piece of Haskell code -

```
data A = A Int Int | B

m :: A -> Int
m a = case a of
  A{} -> 1
  _ -> 2
```

What is the `A{}` doing here? Does the `{}` automatically match for any number of arguments?

I have a feeling that this is exploiting the fact that Haskell record syntax desugars to a bunch of functions and a regular Algebraic Datatype. Is that the case?

Comment: Learn something new every day, and I've been programming Haskell for 5 years now; never seen the syntax in my life.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, `A{}` matches any value constructed with the `A` constructor, regardless of whether the type has been declared with record syntax or not.

The [language report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-490003.15) specifies

> The expression F {}, where F is a data constructor, is legal whether or not F was declared with record syntax (provided F has no strict fields — see the fourth bullet above); it denotes F ⊥1 … ⊥n, where n is the arity of F.

The 'fourth bullet' mentioned in the parenthesis states that it is a static error to construct a value with record syntax which omits a strict field.

And in the section on [pattern matching](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-580003.17), one of the grammar rules for patterns is

```
apat -> qcon { fpat1 , … , fpatk }      (labeled pattern, k ≥ 0)
```

and the semantics are given in the subsection on formal semantics of pattern-matching (3.17.3) as

```
(o) case  v  of {  K  {} ->  e ; _ ->  e′ }
        = case  v  of {
            K _… _ ->  e ; _ ->  e′ }
```

Comment: This syntax is useful, because even if the number of arguments to the constructor `A` changes, the function definition need not change. With regular pattern matching (e.g. `A _ _ -> ...`) this would not be the case.

Comment: @Daniel - yet in this case we are speaking not of expressions, but patterns. I think `F{}` should be equivalent to `F _1 _2 ... _n`where *n* is the arity of the constructor.

Comment: @Ingo Right. Only looked at the 'informal semantics' section last night, didn't find anything there, but the expression part stood out. Found it in the formal semantics section after a few hours of sleep.

Comment: @DanBurton I don't think it's just about numbers of arguments possibly changing. I use the `A{}` syntax just because I find a case branch that reads `(A _ _ _ _ _)` (there are many cases in which the parentheses will be necessary) more difficult to read. It's about not writing things that you don't care about, so it's clear you don't care about them.